# Which Pokemon game claiming to be X-Y is this really?

Tags: pokemon-series, game-identification

There's a Pokemon game claiming to be Pokemon X-Y hosted [on PlayRetroGames.com](https://www.playretrogames.com/1111-pokemon-x-y).

[image: Pokemon "X-Y" Title Screen]

I don't think it's Pokemon XY, it seems closer to Alpha Sapphire. It has locations such as Petalburg City and Rustboro City.

Which game is this, actually?

Answer (score 3):

Judging the years on the first screen, that's a hacked version of **Pokemon Emerald**.
You can see the same intro in this video:

Comment: We have Frogadier so it can't be Emerald.

Comment: @user2617804 do you understand what "hacked" means? The base game is Emerald, cities and intro are the same, only the Pokemon were modded to be the ones in 6th gen.

Comment: There is all sorts of hacked games. You should include your details in your answer. Pokemon Rusty is a hacked game without any obvious non Fire Red elements.

Comment: What do you mean? You asked for the actual game on which that XY is based, and it's clearly Pokemon Emerald for the reasons I wrote. What else is missing?